# Maven, Jetty, JOTM

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, jotm

I have been unable to configure JOTM ontop of Jetty inside a Maven build environment.  The exception I get when I try to run my application is the following:

```
2009-07-21 19:47:23.499::WARN:  Config error at <New id="UserTransaction" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction"><Arg>
                <Ref id="ut"/>
            </Arg></New>
    [INFO] Jetty server exiting.
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Failure

    A flat name can only have a single component
```

I am using this as a reference:http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/JOTM

jetty.xml
(jettyConfig in maven's pom.xml, this is actually being seen)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure id="Server" class="org.mortbay.jetty.Server">
<!-- Configure a Jotm instance which provides a javax.transaction.TransactionManager     -->
    <!-- and a javax.transaction.UserTransaction implementation.                             -->
    <New id="jotm" class="org.objectweb.jotm.Jotm">
        <Arg type="boolean">True</Arg>
        <Arg type="boolean">False</Arg>
        <Call id="tm" name="getTransactionManager"/>
        <Call id="ut" name="getUserTransaction"/>
    </New>

    <!-- Set up the UserTransaction impl from JOTM as the transaction manager for jetty      -->
    <!--
    <New id="UserTransaction" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="ut"/>
        </Arg>
    </New>
    -->
    <New id="userTransaction" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Resource">
        <Arg></Arg>
        <Arg>javax.transaction.TransactionManager</Arg>
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="ut"/>
        </Arg>
    </New>


    <New id="tx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.plus.naming.Transaction">
        <Arg>
            <Ref id="ut"/>
        </Arg>
    </New>

    <!-- If you want to be able to set up more references in webapp specific files -->
    <!-- such as context deployment files and WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml files, you     -->
    <!-- need to save a reference to the JOTM tm object:                           -->
    <!--
    <Call name="setAttribute">
    <Arg>tm</Arg>
    <Arg><Ref id="tm"/></Arg>
    </Call>
    -->
</Configure>
```

carol.properties (not so sure this is being seen, but from the exception, is this even relevant?)

```
carol.start.ns=false
carol.start.jndi=false
carol.protocols=jrmp
carol.start.rmi=false
carol.jvm.rmi.local.call=true
carol.jndi.java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.mortbay.naming
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Walter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is carol.properties located in your project?

Maven resources need to be under src/main/resources. Jetty expects carol.properties to be in the resources folder.

So you may need to move carol.properties to src/main/resources/resources so the file is copied to target/resources by the process-resources stage before Jetty is launched.

Comment: Hmm - ok, I will try that later.  Hopefully that is all I need?

The error sounds more like a configuration issue to me (syntax), but I will try that later.

Comment: I tried that, but I am getting the same message.  Here is where the carol.properties is when building the war:

/WEB-INF/classes/resources/carol.properties

Answer (score 0):

It seems that carol is using own `carol.jar/carol.properties` file instead of yours.
i prepared an example project with jta in jetty 8 with modified `carol.jar/carol.properties` file. there it is http://github.com/beolnix/jta-in-jetty8 . Seems that all is OK, (commit, rollback - no problem) but sometimes the `org.omg.CORBA.BAD_INV_ORDER` exception appears. In my example this exception is ignored

```
try {
    ret = ctx.proceed()
    tx.commit()
} catch (org.omg.CORBA.BAD_INV_ORDER e) {
    //nop
} catch (Throwable e) {
    tx.rollback()
    throw new TransactionException(e.getMessage())
}
```

because it does not influence the result of the transaction processing